# Conflicting changes to the role ... in EF4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a POCO code first model which requires what is effectively a recursive reference. When I try to create entities I get the "Conflicting changes to the role ..." error as per the title.

Here are a set of simplified classes to illustrate the problem:

```
    public class Master
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Query2 Query { get; set; }
}
public class Query2
{
    public Query2()
    {
        Columns = new List<Column2>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Column2> Columns { get; set; }
}
public class Column2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Query2 Query { get; set; }
}
```

The problem exists with the property Column2.Query.

Here is the code to generate automatic sample data:

```
    public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Master> Masters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Query2> Queries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Column2> Columns { get; set; }
}
public class TestContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TestContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(TestContext context)
    {
        Master master = new Master() { Name = "Test" };
        master.Query = new Query2() { Name = "Query1" };
        Column2 col = new Column2() { Name = "Column1" };
        master.Query.Columns.Add(col);
        col.Query = new Query2() { Name = "Query2" };
        col.Query.Columns.Add(new Column2() { Name = "Column2" });
        context.Masters.Add(master);
    }
}
```

And this fires off the error:

```
        private void Test2()
    {
        ZapDatabase(@"D:\Visual Studio\TestDPDatabase\TestDPDatabase\TestContext.sdf");
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(new TestContextInitializer());
        using (TestContext cont = new TestContext())
        {
            var result = cont.Masters.Include("Query").Include("Query.Columns").Include("Query.Columns.Query").Include("Query.Columns.Query.Columns").ToList();
            int objects = result.Count;
        }
    }
```

I have checked a number of instances of people reporting this error and seeking a solution, all of which I can understand the answer but none have this recursive structure.

Many thanks for any assistance offered.

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your assistance. Here is the full error: Conflicting changes to the role 'Column2_Query_Target' of the relationship 'TestDPDatabase.Domain2.Column2_Query' have been detected.

Comment: Have you done any mappings to tell Ef about the relationships?

Comment: If you have done entityconfiguration clasees to tell the framework that query on column refers to the parent, adding the column to the parent, then changing the context of what Query2 refers to will cause this sort of problem. Make sure you've mapped it forward only (ie cascading) as it might be looking for a recurisive parent/child relationship implied.

Comment: I have not done any mappings, in theory they should be quite simple. I shall try mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the entities you're creating in your `Seed()` method conflict with the relationships the EF is inferring.  By default, when you have something like

```
public class Query2
{
  ...
  public virtual ICollection<Column2> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Column2
{
  ...
  public virtual Query2 Query { get; set; }
}
```

...the EF assumes that it's a reciprocal relationship.  So when you add `col` to `master.Query.Columns`, but set `col.Query` to a new instance, it doesn't like it -- the relationship isn't satisfied.

If that's not the way you want the relationship to work, you may have to override [`OnModelCreating()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in your `DbContext` and use the Fluent API to define how things should be set up.

Comment: The line col.Query = new Query2() is correct, col should have a brand new Query2 and not a reference to that attached to master. If I make the change which you suggest then although the data is wrong, I no longer get the error. I shall try adjusting relationships in code to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to be explicit about both ends of the relationships and to add a mapping as follows:

```
    public class Master
{
    [Key()]
    public int MasterId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Query2 Query { get; set; }
}
public class Query2
{
    public Query2()
    {
        Columns = new List<Column2>();
    }
    [Key()]
    public int QueryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Master Master { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Column2> Columns { get; set; }
}
public class Column2
{
    [Key()]
    public int ColumnId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Query2 Query { get; set; }
    public virtual Query2 ColQuery { get; set; }
}
```

and the mapping

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Query2>().HasRequired(q => q.Master).WithRequiredPrincipal(m => m.Query);
    }
```

My feeling as an EF newbie is that it is better to be explicit rather than to depend on defaults.